# Calling async function from a synchronous function causing x.result to hang ... fix it with extension?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

Take this async function:

```
Public Async Function MyAsyncFunction() As Task(Of String)
    Return Await SomeFunctionThatReturnsAString()
End Function
```

If I call it from a synchronous function like this:

```
Public Function MySyncFunction() As String
    Return MyAsyncFunction.Result
End Function
```

... the function hangs.

I wondered if it is possible to write an extension like this (the extension below does not work):

```
Public Module TaskExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function SyncronousResult(Of T)(aTask As Task(Of T)) As T
        Dim result As T = Nothing
        Task.Run(Sub()
                     result = aTask.Result
                 End Sub).Wait()
        Return result
    End Function

End Module
```

... so I could call it like this:

```
Public Function MySyncFunction() As String
    Return MyAsyncFunction.SyncronousResult
End Function
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal solution is [*not* to block on asynchronous code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (as I explain on my blog).

But, if you're in a situation where you literally *can't* use `Await` (for some reason), then you can try using one of the techniques in my [Brownfield Async article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058). Note that there is no general-purpose solution that works everywhere.

The one you suggest is blocking for the result in a thread pool thread, which may or may not work. In the example code you posted, it wouldn't work because `MyAsyncFunction` has already captured the UI context and will attempt to resume in that context.

What you *can* try is call `MyAsyncFunction` from inside a delegate passed to `Task.Run` and then call `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on the returned task. That works in *most* cases. In my article I refer to this as the "Thread Pool Hack".